# 9 patch images not resizing in width.How to fix this?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am using 9 patch images in my application.I set my 9 patch image as text background.Now it is resizing in height only.Width of the image remains the same.How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

for 9-patch images, the marked-top-edge and the marked-left-edge are the extendable edges, however the marked-bottom-edge and the marked-right-edge are which limit the contents' position.

If you want to resize the width but marked the bottom-edge nor the top-edge, the 9-patch image can't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In a 9patch image, top edge shows the width area to be expanded. Just make sure you have only highlighted the to be expanded area on of top edge.

Comment: Its a chat bubble.so which all areas should be highlighted ?

Comment: She has problem in resizing width only , thats why I just mentioned top edge.

Comment: @himanshu i will post my image.could u please tell me how to edit it in draw9patch tool ?

Comment: Please post it. I have already done a corrected version of the mdpi bubble shown above, just for fun.

Comment: Can anyone demonstrate how to edit this image in draw9patch tool please ??

Comment: @Artoo Detoo Please see the link

Answer (score 0):

If your image is like the bubble below or almost similar, then the nine-patch should have the top edge specifying the width that should expand, the left edge to present the height. The bottom and right edges are for the regions within which the content should be displayed, you could experiment with that.

[image]

EDIT: As per Artoo Detoo (changed the right and the bottom edges)

Comment: These images aren't done well. The contents will flood OUTSIDE THE BUBBLE. Because of the right and bottom padding markers not properly set

Comment: @ArtooDetoo iv mentioned that in the answer that maria could play around with the bottom and right edges, m not expected to do the homework but just assist or probably give a hint

Comment: Yes, anyway these images aren't perfect... I made a variant, for fun, which seems to work nicely.

Comment: Yes true, i saw the answer :)